# How can I sort variable array in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

this question is so crucial, and it took me days, but I couldn't solve it. so I receive an array of objects called `shoppingItems` that is a large array with `800` items.

each `item` is an object and overall data structure is like this:

```
[
  {ID:13242, Name:'something', color:`red`, price :150 },
  {ID:13242, Name:'something1', color:`green` , price : 200},
...
]
```

since the array is large, I decided to render it partially per each scroll using my custom hook. It has some optional props

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const useOptimizeListRenderPerformance = (
  largeListArray,
  additionalFn,
  FnParams,
  ApplyFilter
) => {
  const [itemsToShow, setItemsToShow] = useState(5);
  const [list, setList] = useState([]);
  const [startY, setStartY] = useState(0);
  const [activated, setActivated] = useState(false);
  const [firstCall, setFirstCall] = useState(true);

  const handleScroll = (e) => {
    if (e.deltaY > 0) {
      setItemsToShow((prev) => prev + 1);
    } else {
      setItemsToShow((prev) => (prev > 5 ? prev - 1 : prev));
    }
  };

  const handleTouchStart = (e) => {
    setStartY(e.touches[0].clientY);
  };

  const handleTouchMove = (e) => {
    const currentY = e.touches[0].clientY;
    if (currentY > startY) {
      setItemsToShow((prev) => prev + 1);
    } else {
      setItemsToShow((prev) => (prev > 5 ? prev - 1 : prev));
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (largeListArray) {
      let updatedList = largeListArray.slice(0, itemsToShow);
      if (additionalFn) {
        updatedList = additionalFn(updatedList, ...FnParams);
      }
      ApplyFilter
        ? setList(ApplyFilter(largeListArray, FnParams))
        : setList(updatedList);
    }
  }, [largeListArray, itemsToShow, FnParams]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setActivated(true);
    setFirstCall(false);
  }, []);

  return {
    list,
    handleTouchMove,
    handleScroll,
    handleTouchStart,
    activated,
    firstCall,
  };
};

export default useOptimizeListRenderPerformance;
```

now at each scroll it shows 5 items. that means, 5 items at first and then 10 and 15 and so on.

this is my problem now:

I store selected items in `localstorage` so if user accidentally refreshes the page, they will not go away. I store the exact object in array.

now I want to bring them to the top of the array, but I can't do it properly since the array length changes. some items stay in bottom because they are not even rendered yet at component mount.

on the other hand I use such function to bring selected items to the top and this makes problem even more terrible:

```
export const updateLargeArray = (largeArray, globalItems) => {
  // Short circuit: if globalItems is not present or is an empty array, return largeArray
  if (!globalItems || globalItems.length === 0) {
    return largeArray;
  }

  // Create a Set of globalItems IDs for faster lookup
  const globalItemsIds = new Set(globalItems.map((item) => item.ID));

  // Filter out items from largeArray that have matching IDs with globalItems
  const filteredLargeArray = largeArray.filter(
    (item) => !globalItemsIds.has(item.ID)
  );

  // Insert globalItems at the beginning of the filteredLargeArray
  return [...globalItems, ...filteredLargeArray];
};
```

large array is that huge array with `800` items and `globalItems` are selected items.

I tried to limit the number of what can be shown instead of this magical tricks to partially rendering the array but our customer rejected it.

Answer (score 1):

I won't comment specifically on your code, but I'll show you how I would proceed in this case with an example. Surely you can easily adapt it with minor modifications

The first thing is to copy shoppingItems Array to another array, to prevent changing the original full data. Let's call it itemsToBeDisplayed.

```
    let itemsToBeDisplayed= [ ...shoppingItems ]
```

Then, we create an array to add the items already displayed, starting with an empty list.

```
    let itemsAlreadyDisplayed = []
```

For your case, we can create a function that moves N random elements from itemsToBeDisplayed to itemsAlreadyDisplayed:

```
    function sortItems(numberOfItems) {
        for (let i=0; i < numberOfItems; i++) {
            let randomIndex = Math.floor( Math.random()*itemsToBeDisplayed.length )
            itemsAlreadyDisplayed.push( itemsToBeDisplayed[ randomIndex ] )
            itemsToBeDisplayed.splice( randomIndex, 1)
        }
        console.log(itemsToBeDisplayed)
        console.log(itemsAlreadyDisplayed)
    }
```

The Math.Random() generates a number from 0 to 1. After multiplying that by the array length, we get a random index from the array. Then, we add this element to itemsAlreadyDisplayed and remove it from itemsToBeDisplayed using the splice method. In your case, you can use the same approach, and replace the last console.log() lines with React Hooks setItemsAlreadyDisplayed, etc....

Cheers!